# Reinsert comments for a single user in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been using a macro by Rodney Atkins called "ReinsertComments" that was posted by someone in the comments section over at CyberText (see macro below): https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/word-removing-reviewer-names/. It reinserts all the comments in a Word document. I would like to find a way, if at all possible, to reinsert only one user's comments, but not all other users' comments.

1. Is it possible to specify per author which comments will be
   reinserted?
2. Could you run an If/Then statement to specify a user name for the comments to be reinserted? Perhaps something along the lines of

```
If myComment.Author = "Jane" Then
```

3. If a version of that is possible, where should I insert the If/Then
   and End If portion in the macro below?

Thanks to all! :)

---

```
Sub CommentsReinsert()

Dim myComment As Comment
Dim myComText As String
Dim comStart
Dim comEnd
Dim i

On Error GoTo Done
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True Then
With ActiveDocument
.TrackRevisions = False
End With
End If

For i = ActiveDocument.Comments.Count To 1 Step -1
Set myComment = ActiveDocument.Comments(i)
myComText = myComment.Range.Text
comStart = myComment.Scope.Start
comEnd = myComment.Scope.End
myComment.Reference.Select
myComment.Delete
ActiveDocument.Range(comStart, comEnd).Select
ActiveDocument.Comments.Add _
Range:=Selection.Range, Text:=myComText
Next i

ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Done:

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the point of re-inserting the comments? You can change the author name without doing that. Moreover, the code you're using will both change the date of the comment and destroy any formatting the original comment might have had.

Comment: Thank you for this. You cannot selectively change another user's name, you can only selectively change your own name. The only way to change all names is non-selective: use Document Properties to remove personal information, including all names and comment dates, from the file on save. Sometimes you have multiple reviewers/authors, resulting in separate comments or nested replies, but several names need to be anonymized for blind review. Nobody cares about the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use code like:

```
Sub ReinsertComments()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim bRev As Boolean, i As Long, Rng As Range, Cmt As Comment
With ActiveDocument
  bRev = .TrackRevisions
  .TrackRevisions = False
  For i = .Comments.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Comments(i)
      Select Case .Author
        Case "Jane"
          Set Rng = .Range
          Set Cmt = ActiveDocument.Comments.Add(Range:=.Scope, Text:="")
          Cmt.Range.FormattedText = Rng.FormattedText ': Cmt.Author = "Anon."
          Rng.Comments(1).Delete
      End Select
    End With
  Next
  .TrackRevisions = bRev
End With
Set Cmt = Nothing: Set Rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Unlike the code you posted, the above preserves the original comment's formatting. Note the commented-out code for changing the inserted comment's author name.

An alternative approach would be to temporarily change the UserName & Initials in the Word Options, to that of the commentator, then simply change the Comment.Author property to whatever other name you want - without all the deletion/reinsertion circumlocution.

I imagine people would be concerned about the dates if there are replies to comments and the above macro was deleting then reinserting them with a different date...

Comment: That is spectacular! It can't handle multiply-authored nested replies by reinserting the comment as a reply in the original place in the replies, but this is so useful. Thank you!

Comment: As to your suggestion for an alternative approach: the problem is when co-authors or reviewers don't temporarily change their author name while commenting. You need to change their user names after the fact. Say you have two authors whose names are Joan Doe (Author 1) and John Doe (Author 2). Neither have changed their author name to Author 1 or Author 2 while commenting. The workaround is to change your own user name to Author 1 and reinsert the comments made by Joan Doe, making them all now appear as Author 1. Then change your name to Author 2, and reinsert the comments by John Doe.

Comment: Is there a way to have your macro above reinsert comment replies in the place they appear? As your macro is written, if Jane's comment is a reply (i.e., the last reply, or a reply in the middle of multiple replies), it is reinserted as a separate new comment, not as the reply.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my previous reply, you could use the alternative approach of:

```
Sub ChangeCommentAuthor()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim bRev As Boolean, i As Long, UsrNm As String, UsrIn As String, bUsr As Boolean
UsrNm = Application.UserName: UsrIn = Application.UserInitials: bUsr = Options.UseLocalUserInfo
'Nominate the UserName & Initials to change from
Application.UserName = "Figgie 10": Application.UserInitials = "F": Options.UseLocalUserInfo = True
With ActiveDocument
  bRev = .TrackRevisions
  .TrackRevisions = False
  For i = .Comments.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .Comments(i)
      'Nominate the UserName & Initials to change to
      If .Author = Application.UserName Then .Author = "John Doe": .Initial = "JD"
    End With
  Next
  .TrackRevisions = bRev
End With
Application.UserName = UsrNm: Application.UserInitials = UsrIn: Options.UseLocalUserInfo = bUsr
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. If I could check both macros as answers, I would. Much obliged.